# YOURLS: Need to expand characters in Custom short URL

Tags: php, url, short, url-shortener, yourls

I used YOURLS (yourls.org) for creating custom links for my domain, say like go.example.com/customname. But by default they allow only few characters for that custom name, I want to increase it further.

Default shortening : go.example.com/hostga

By tweaking I should get : go.example.com/hostgator

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With v1.5 there appears to be no such limitation, BUT using the sample index.php, the CSS cuts off the shortened URL, so it might appear that there's a limitation (though there is not).  I tried it with a 20 character keyword, with hyphenation allowed, and it worked as expected.